# Finite sample probability

Tags: probability

Two points are chosen at random on a line of unit length. How can I find the probability that each of the three line segments so formed will have a length $> \frac{1}{4}$?

I have tried making a unit square as suggested by my former adviser but I can't seem to find the answer as it seem to be theoretical.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you made a unit square?  Did you look at the areas where the length of all three segments had length $> \frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: yep! i only used the half triangle. then marked points 1/4, 1/2 and 3/4 for x and y.and extend the points. giving me an area where you get points greater than 1/4 but less than 3/4. but i don't know how to continue from there.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine choosing one point $X$, and then a second point $Y$. We assume that "at random" means here that the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are *uniform* on $[0,1]$ and that $X$ and $Y$ are *independent*.

We want the probability that $1/4\lt X\lt 3/4$ and $1/4\lt Y\lt 3/4$ and $|X-Y|\gt 1/4$.

Draw the usual square. Draw the line $x=1/4$, $x=3/4$, $y=1/4$, $y=3/4$. Look at the square $K$ bounded by these lines.

Draw the two lines $x-y=\pm 1/4$. We want to find the probability that $(X,Y)$ lands in the part of $K$ that is not between these two lines. That consists of two isosceles right-angled triangles. Each of these triangles has legs $\frac{1}{4}$, so their combined area is $\frac{1}{16}$.

Since the ordered pair $(X,Y)$ has uniform distribution on the full square,  our probability is $\frac{1}{16}$.

Comment: thats just great! thank you so much sir! :) will definitely try this later when i get home! Thank you! Hope you can respond again later.

Comment: You are welcome. I have left finding that the legs of each triangle are indeed $\frac{1}{4}$ to you. As a hint, find where $x-y=1/4$ meets $y=1/4$.  As to respond again later, it is latish evening here. If difficulty arises (but it should not), I can help further tomorrow.

Comment: can i ask why we should make a unit square? :) i dont quite get the reason of doing so.

Comment: The choice of numbers is from a line of unit length. So we can take the random variable  $X$ as ranging over the interval from $0$ to $1$, also $Y$. So the ordered pair $(X, Y)$ ranges over the ordered pairs $(x,y)$ where $0\le x\le 1$, $0\le y\le 1$. This is the square with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(1,0)$. That is the square we draw.